# Python pdf2txt cleanup issue

Tags: python, pdf, text

I am extracting text from a pdf file but i am facing some post extraction issues.

**where i get**

```
s = 'Our offer is \n4\n4\nProcessing\n\nPipeline\nPipeline\n2\nA\nm\na\nz\no\nn\nE\nC\n2\n'
s.replace('\n','')
Our offer is 44ProcessingPipelinePipeline2AmazonEC23
```

**But what i would like is to get :**

Our offer is 44 Processing Pipeline Pipeline 2 Amazon EC 2 3

**my Code :**

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument()
parser.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(parser)
doc.initialize('')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
laparams.char_margin = 13.0
laparams.word_margin = 13.0
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
extracted_text = ''

for page in doc.get_pages():
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lt_obj in layout:
        if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
            extracted_text += lt_obj.get_text()

print(extracted_text)



from nltk import tokenize
#split by sentence
newtext = tokenize.sent_tokenize(extracted_text)
```

then with the output i run a replace on the \n

**My idea is to find the neighbors of the **\n** and evaluate**

if

when **\n** has no previous neighbors(empty space) but has following replace '(\n+empty space') with (empty space)

when **\n** has neighbors both sides replace '(\n) with (empty space)

when **\n** has uppercase following neighbors and no previous neighbors(empty space) replace '(\n+'Uppercase') with (empty space)

I think i am getting to deep into this and there might be someone who has done this before.

'Our offer is IO)\n4\n4\nProcessing\n\nPipeline\nPipeline\n2\nA\nm\na\nz\no\nn\nE\nC\n2\n'

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expression seems to be pretty difficult. I got the following solution, not elegant, but does the job.

```
s = 'Our offer is \n4\n4\nProcessing\n\nPipeline\nPipeline\n2\nA\nm\na\nz\no\nn\nE\nC\n2\n'

prev_c = '\0'

out = ''
for ii,cc in enumerate(s):
  cc = s[ii]
  c = s[ii+1] if ii<len(s)-1 else '\0'
  if cc=='\n':
    if prev_c==' ' or \
       prev_c=='\n' or \
       prev_c.isdigit() and c.isdigit() or \
       prev_c.islower() and c.islower() or \
       prev_c.isupper() and c.isupper() or \
       prev_c.isupper() and c.islower():
      pass
    else:
      out += ' ' 
  else:
    out += cc

  prev_c = cc

print(out)
```

However, I'm pretty sure that you will encounter other cases that this does not work. For example the following sentence,

"2head P2P solution with hyphens(-) and other CamelCases! OoO"

Comment: Hi,Thx very simple solution for my use case, but like you mention this can fall into other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution is to use regular expressions. I was trying to write a suitable pattern, but I am not an expert with regular expressions or patterns. I don't know why it is not working. This is the closest I could get. The code:

```
import re

s = "Our offer is \n4\n4\nProcessing\n\nPipeline\nPipeline\n2\nA\nm\na\nz\no\nn\nE\nC\n2\n"
s1 = "A\nb\nc"
w = s.replace('\n',' ')
print(w)
# Our offer is 44ProcessingPipelinePipeline2AmazonEC23


pattern = '([A-Z](\n[a-z])+[\n])|([A-Z](\n[A-Z])+[\n])'

result = re.findall(pattern, s) 

m = re.search(pattern, s)
iter = re.finditer(pattern, s)
indices = [m.start(0) for m in iter]

print(result)
print(indices)
```

output:

```
$ python3 a.py 
Our offer is  4 4 Processing  Pipeline Pipeline 2 A m a z o n E C 2 
[('A\nm\na\nz\no\nn\n', '\nn', '', ''), ('', '', 'E\nC\n', '\nC')]
[50, 62]
```

Good luck.